# Calculate latency using WinSock

Tags: c++, winsock, latency

As the title says, how can I calculate the latency between a client and a server in ms using WinSock 2.2 ?

Comment: Time the trip using the built in timer. `GetTickCount` will work fine for this.

Comment: You cannot compute one-way latency unless the clocks are exactly in sync.  NTP isn't going to give you millisecond synchronization, but PTP might.  You can compute the round-trip latency, and you can compute the one-way standard deviation of latency for a collection of samples.

Comment: It is possible to solve this problem quite well, but not with any Windows API, which is what you are asking for.  For example, TS Associates (http://www.ts-a.com/) will sell you a solution that works quite well.  You might notice that their web site doesn't bother to list prices...

Comment: @sean GetTickCount has 10-16ms resolution, so it might not be good enough.  And it is not useful if the client and server are on different machines.

Answer (score 0):

I think, realistically, you can only calculate a roundtrip time, unless you have very good control of both servers. If you can make the other end reply in some way, you can easily calculate the ime from sending packet X until you get the reply for packet X.

Since, in this case, you are in control of the time "at send and at receive", you don't have to worry about sending packets with time information that has to match with the other end.